# Build failed when trying to create the Database Migration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I'm getting an error message when trying to make Database Migration. 
since I'm new to EF I don't know what problem can cause such error.
[image]

Comment: Rebuild your project, any errors?

Comment: Follow the Microsoft link that will help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I rebuild it, I think I mistakenly deleted csproj File during a process, that was the error I got in the VS, Can it be the problem cause? and if yes how can I add a new csproj file to the project because I can't find any template in add new items